# Inserting XML Element after last specific node/element

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I want to add elements after last child in the XML. But I got an error.

```
<XML ID="Microsoft Search Thesaurus">
  <thesaurus xmlns="x-schema:tsSchema.xml">
    <diacritics_sensitive>0</diacritics_sensitive>
    <expansion>
        <sub>Internet Explorer</sub>
        <sub>IE</sub>
        <sub>IE5</sub>
    </expansion>
    <replacement>
        <pat>NT5</pat>
        <pat>W2K</pat>
        <sub>Windows 2000</sub>
    </replacement>
    <expansion>
        <sub>run</sub>
        <sub>jog</sub>
    </expansion>
    <expansion>
      <sub>home</sub>
      <sub>house</sub>
    </expansion>
  </thesaurus>
</XML>
```

My code is below and I encounter this error, when I debug the code.

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled.
>
> > Sequence contains no elements.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("tseng.xml");  //load the xml file.
IEnumerable<XElement> MemberList = doc.Element("XML").Elements("thesaurus");
var Member = new XElement("expansion",
                 new XElement("sub", "home"),
                 new XElement("sub", "house")
             );
MemberList.Last().AddAfterSelf(Member);  //add node to the last element.
doc.Save("tseng.xml");
```

This error is for specific line:

```
MemberList.Last().AddAfterSelf(Member);
```

I don't know what is my problem on this code. How can I add element after last `<expansion>` node to my XML file?

Can you help me for this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<thesaurus>` element has an `xmlns` attribute that specifies a namespace, so you need to add the namespace to all the element names. Also, you should use `Add` instead of `AddAfterSelf` if you want the new `<expansion>` element to appear inside `<thesaurus>` instead of after it.

```cs
XNamespace ns = "x-schema:tsSchema.xml";
IEnumerable<XElement> MemberList = doc.Element("XML").Elements(ns + "thesaurus");
var Member = new XElement(ns + "expansion",
                 new XElement(ns + "sub", "home"),
                 new XElement(ns + "sub", "house"));
MemberList.Last().Add(Member);  //add node to the last element.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify namespace explicitly for `thesaurus` element, as it is different than the one for root `XML` node:

```
XNamespace ns = "x-schema:tsSchema.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("tseng.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> MemberList = doc.Element("XML").Elements(ns + "thesaurus");
```

Also, keep in mind your current code will add new `expansion` element **after** `thesaurus` one, not as its children. If you want to add new `expansion` element under the last `thesaurus` element, you should use this code instead:

```
var MemberList = root.Elements(ns + "thesaurus");
var Member = new XElement(ns + "expansion",
    new XElement(ns + "sub", "home"),
    new XElement(ns + "sub", "house")
);
MemberList.Last().Add(Member);
```

This will produce XML similar to example below:

```
<XML ID="Microsoft Search Thesaurus">
  <thesaurus xmlns="x-schema:tsSchema.xml">
    <diacritics_sensitive>0</diacritics_sensitive>
    <!-- elided: new element goes here -->
    <expansion>
      <sub>home</sub>
      <sub>house</sub>
    </expansion>
  </thesaurus>
</XML>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. I delete the root.Elements(ns+"thesaurus"); and debug the code. It is done. Michael Liu posted the correct code to add element for thesaurus xml file.